# RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 6 in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have gone through many solutions but nothing worked for me. please have a look at my code. I could not find any issue.
The length of the list is 5 but I don't get why the error is of 0: 6 index. The list's length has no relation with 0: 6. I also checked it using a list of length 4.

```
 Consumer<ProductsProvider>(builder: (context, product, _) {
             List<Widget> widgets = [];

            if (product.prod!.isNotEmpty) {
              product.prod!.forEach((element) {
                log(" element price = ${element.price}");
                log("value === ${value++}");
                widgets.add(CustomerProductsWidget(
                  isReseller: false,
                  productData: element,
                ));

              });
            } else {
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Text(
                  "No Product Available",
                ),
              );
            }

            return Center(
              child: Wrap(
                alignment: WrapAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
                children: widgets.toList(),
              ),
            );
          }),
```

and My ProductsProvider code is as:

```
  class ProductsProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<ProductData>? prod = [];

  updateProd({List<ProductData>? newProd}) {
    prod = newProd;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: Where do you use this incrementing value++?

Comment: Probably the error is comming from your ProductsProvider. Please post a print from the error on your console

Comment: @VladimirGadzhov I am not using it. It is just to check how many times it's executing.

Comment: @MateusVenâncio I added the provider's code. Please check.